# В файл записывается только текст до пробела java

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

Есть вот такая функция, которая вызывается в главном методе, нужно чтобы она записывала в конец существующего файла некоторый текст, но она записывает текст только до первого пробела. Как сделать, чтобы введенный в консоль текст записывался полностью? Среда NetBeans.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

    static void Files(){
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Path ----   ");
    String path = read.next().trim();
    if(path.length() == 0){
        System.out.println("Type path");
        Files();
    }else{
        System.out.print("Name of file ----  ");
        String filename = read.next().trim();
        if(filename.length() == 0){
            System.out.print("File must be named! ");
            Files();
        }
        File my = new File(path);
        if(!my.exists()){
            System.out.print("Directory is not exist. Create it? Any/n - " );
            String variety = read.next();
            switch(variety){
        case "n":
            System.out.print("Creating cancelled!");
            break;

        case "н":
            System.out.print("Creating cancelled!");
            break;
        default:
            my.mkdir();
            try{
                File my1 = new File(path+"/"+filename);
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(my1, true);
                System.out.println("Type text");
                my1.createNewFile();
                writer.append(read.next());
                writer.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.err.println("There are some mistakes in your path or filename. Try again");
                Files();
            }
        }

    }else{
        try{
            File my1 = new File(path +"/"+filename);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(my1, true);
                my1.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("Type text");
                writer.write(read.next());
                writer.close();
                read.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.err.println("There are some mistakes in your path or filename. Try again");
                Files();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Заменить `read.next()` на `read.nextLine()`.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev в таком случае, на этом месте программа заканчивает выполнятся, файл создается, но вписать в него значение нельзя.